# Is there a more theoretical approach to studying physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, mathematical-physics, soft-question, education

I have read some physics papers in theoretical particle physics and all of them were based on computation, they had some mile long equations and the result was always the proof of some formula.

I am interested in studying physics but those endless computations are not my cup of tea, therefore I was wondering if there is a more theoretical approach to the study of physics and in particular, particle physics.

I am looking for some branch of particle physics that uses set theoretic arguments like those used in pure mathematics (abstract algebra, topology, etc) and that has a goal to prove more general theorems and not just formulae.

To put it simple, I am looking for a branch that by thinking in pure mathematics we prove physics.

Comment: At that point you might as well just do mathematics. Computation is the bread and butter of the theoretical physicist, otherwise you cannot test your models and make your predictions.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed since it is not opinion based, I am asking for something very specific.

Comment: You can only test a theory by comparing it with the results of experiment, hence the need for computation.

Comment: I understand the importance of computation, but is there any other, more abstract approach? For example by studying spaces like manifolds, varieties etc from a pure mathematical point of view, reason about particle interactions or other physical phenomena.

Comment: You may like **mathematical** physics better than theoretical physics. Mathematical physics is really mathematics and its spectrum ranges from very computational works to very abstract works. There are branches of mathematical physics for most branches of theoretical physics, so you should be able to find something you like.

Comment: The problem with abstract theory is that you can construct seemingly reasonable theories, but when you test their predictions against reality (by experiment) you find they fail.  Or they produce prediction of phenomena that do not even occur.  Many modern theories are simply too complex to allow explicit results to be developed without computation, so you need the computation to test the theory against reality.  The **only** way to prove a theory in physics is test it against reality.  A theory that is mathematically perfect can fail to agree with reality.

Comment: Mathematical physics is a respectable (though not particularly fashionable) branch of mathematics. One of Hilbert's problems from the early 20th century was to put theoretical physics on a rigorous, axiomatic footing. There is also a Millenium prize problem for proving the existence of Yang Mills theory, which underlies the standard model. In theoretical physics, it is much more important for theories to provide physical insight than mathematical rigor. Mathematical physics is more interested in providing a rigorous basis for the mathematical structures that appear in theoretical physics.

Comment: @StephenG Much (most?) of mathematical physics is concerned with well established physical theories. The point is (1) to examine rigorously what are the real implications of a theory (that is, without introducing all kinds of approximations, not part of the theory per se), (2) to define in a consistent way objects that physicists introduce on the intuitive level. It is (usually) not to create new theories or explain new phenomena. Whether this constitutes a useful endeavor is subjective. In my view, it is essential.

Comment: @YvanVelenik The OP wants to "prove physics" starting from and exclusively from mathematics.  This is simply not possible.  Physics, by definition, has to be proven by comparing it's models with the reality.  The value of seeking rigor in the mathematics that physics uses is not one I would dispute, as it helps (at the very least) in defining the limits of validity of a theoretical model.  But you cannot "prove physics" with mathematical rigor alone.  My view is that without understand the experiments you gain no physical insight or understanding to inform how to use the tools of math.

Comment: @StephenG Oh sure. But there are many claims in physics that you can indeed *prove* by pure mathematical reasoning *in the framework of a particular physical theory*. That's what mathematical physicists do and that's how I understood the OP's assertion. If he indeed meant to find the ultimate laws of nature by pure introspection, then this is indeed absurd (or, rather, it's at best philosophy, not physics).

Comment: @YvanVelenik Just to clarify, I was taught physics from a heavily experimentally focused viewpoint, so it has "informed" (or biased :-) ) my viewpoint on this.  My impression is that the OP regards the experimental aspect as unimportant to learning physics, whereas I consider it essential.  I think the OP is, in this sense, kind of setting themselves up to fail to learn physics going the purist math route.

Comment: @StephenG I don't regard experimental physics as unimportant, in fact I never said anything about experimental physics, all I said is that I prefer abstract arguments than endless computations, so I was wondering if this abstract way of thinking can be useful to physics.

Comment: @Kthamil No insult intended, so hopefully none taken.  You did mention "learning physics" hence my comment.  Abstraction *can* be useful, but you have to be doing it with a goal based in the physical world.  Abstraction alone is going to let you "drift" away from real world physics.  I would never recommend *learning* physics from a purely abstract viewpoint.  Maybe the "Theoretical Minimum" books would be a better starting point than math - focus on the physics, less on the math.  Gain an intuition for physics without heavy math (hopefully).